# ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Off', 'On'] in column 0 during fit

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code I do not know where the error is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder,OneHotEncoder

Light = ['On','Off']
Watering = ['Low','High']
# create combinations for all parameters
experiments = [(x,y) for x in Light for y in Watering]
exp_df = pd.DataFrame(experiments,columns=['A','B'])
print(exp_df)
OHE_model = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore')
enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['A','B'],['Low','High']])

encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(exp_df[['A','B']]),columns=['A','B'])
#define the experiments order which must be random
encoded_df['exp_order'] = np.random.choice(np.arange(4),4,replace=False)
encoded_df['outcome'] = [25,37,55,65]
```

and this is the error

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Off', 'On'] in column 0 during fit
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that On and Off are expected in place off A and B.

Use this code for your enc variable instead

```
enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['On','Off'],['Low','High']])
```